# forms - Symfony 2 - default attributes for labels and fields in all forms

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I am using Symfony2 and Twitter Bootstrap along with some customized styles. I would like to have default classes added to 'text' and 'textarea' fields for the whole project unless specified not to use them.

This is the manual way of achieving what I want in one form Type, however it is not efficient at all.

```
$builder
            ->add('name', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Name', 
                'label_attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'col-md-4 control-label'
                    ),
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control input-md'
                    )
                ))
            ->add('description', 'textarea', array(
                'label' => 'Name',
                'label_attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'control-label'
                    ),
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control input-md'
                    )
                ))
            ->add('referenceNo', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Name', 
                'label_attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'col-md-4 control-label'
                    ),
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control input-md'
                    )
                ))
            ->add('client','text',array()) //Don't use styling
```

Should I create a service and call it inside every form Type to get default settings and then pass it as argument? 
Should I extend form_div_layout.html.twig and modify it ([form customization](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html))? Or is there a better and more efficient way of achieving this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First idea: use traits (http://php.net/traits)

Second idea: extend a base form. Call the parent function to get default values.

Both ways are better than creating a service and calling it every time. I prefer using traits to achieve this.